# C program that prints out highest number

Tags: c

So I need to make a C program that prints out the highest number inputed. 
If the input is empty it shouldn't print anything. 
If the input includes anything else than a number it shouldn't print anything. 
example: 
If the input is 1 2 3 2 1 it should print out 3.
If the input is 1 2 a 2 1 it shouldn't print out anything.

This is what i got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int res, max, x;

    res = scanf("%d", &max);
    if (res == 1) {
        while(res != EOF)
        {
            res = scanf("%d", &x);
            if (x > max)
            {
                max=x;
            }
        }
        printf("%d", max);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is, how do i make it print out nothing if it contains a letter like in the example above.
Thank in advance!

Comment: Note that `else { return 0; }` is redundant since if first `scanf` returns anything but `1` you'll never get to the `while` loop and thus you'll get to `return 0;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int res, max, x;

    if(1 != scanf("%d", &max))
        return -1;

    while(EOF != (res = scanf("%d", &x))){
        if(res != 1)
            return -1;
        if (x > max){
            max = x;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int max, x;

   if (scanf("%d", &max) != 1)
   {
      // If there is no number, exit the program.
      return 0;
   }

   while ( scanf("%d", &x) == 1 )
   {
      if (x > max)
      {
         max=x;
      }
   }

   // If we came to the EOF, we didn't see any bad input.
   if ( feof(stdin) )
   {
      printf("Max: %d\n", max);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the input is a number, `scanf` will return `1`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int max, x;
    int result;

    if (scanf("%d", &max) != 1)
        return -1;
    x = max;
    do {
        result = scanf("%d[^\n]", &x);
        if ((result != EOF) && (result != 1))
            return 0;
        else if ((result != EOF) && (x > max))
            max = x;
    } while (result != EOF);

    printf("\n\nMaximum Input : %d\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

the previous program will stop when there is invalid input, i.e. something that is not a number.

Comment: I think the `printf` line should be outside the `do-while` loop.

Comment: @RSahu you're correct, but that'll break the demand to print nothing if a letter appears among the integers.